# How to use "=" in Zsh when aliasing a command

Tags: zsh, alias

I have the following alias:

```
alias ls='exa --icons -H'
```

When using `=ls`, the `=` escapes the alias:

```
$ ls
 Applications   Documents   Downloads   Pictures   Videos   www
```

```
$ =ls
Applications  Documents  Downloads  Pictures  Videos  www
```

How do I define an alias in Zsh?

Comment: Your question doesn't have a question; You should reiterate the question in the body, not have it only in the title. Please read "[ask]" and its linked pages. Also, the [tour] will help you. In addition these are useful… "[How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/153968)"
"[Should I use tags in titles?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)"

Answer (score 2):

Kind of. `=ls` is a distinct word from `ls`, so it doesn't match the name of your defined alias. It's no different than if you had tried to run `xls` or any other version of `ls` with a prefixed character.

However, words starting with `=` later undergo expansion, expanding to the result of a path lookup if such a lookup succeeds. So `=ls` expands to `/bin/ls` (or whatever), and so behaves the same as running `ls` by itself.

`=` expansion is more clearly seen when used somewhere other than command position:

```
% print =ls
/bin/ls
```

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning that an `=` expansion in the command position is a shorter alternative to the `command` builtin, i.e. `=ls *` would have the same effect as `command ls *`. Especially on the command line, I find it more convenient to type, when I want to bypass an alias or function of the same name.